# php error count() displays "Array" or "m"

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I'm trying to display different images from the database that are in the same field but the result is echoed either as "m" or "Array".

Here's my code:

```
$badges = $row['badges'];
$badges = explode(",", $badges);
$badge = count($badges);
if(empty($badges)) {
    $badges = "";
} else {
    $i = 0;
    while($i <= $badge) {
       $badges = "<img src='".$badges[$i]."' /> ";
       $i++;
    }
}
$rank = "<tr><td><img src='".$rank."' /> ".$badges."</td></tr>";
```

$rank is then echoed to the div that I want it to be displayed but the image src is always "m" or when I try putting the while in place of the $rank variable it echoes as "Array". Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: In your `while ` loop you're overwriting your $badges array with a string. Use a different variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use another variable name, like badgeString as the output.  Also, it seems like you want to append all the badges

```
if(empty($badges)) {
    $badgeString = "";
} else {
    $i = 0;
    while($i <= $badge) {
       $badgeString .= "<img src='".$badges[$i]."' /> ";
       $i++;
    }
}
$rank = "<tr><td><img src='".$rank."' /> ".$badgeString."</td></tr>";
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Cheers.